# javascript:Object instance and prototype

Tags: javascript

protype is an object whose internal prototype property is set to Object.prototype and has constructor property in it.but when we do this:

```
x=new Object;//
```

x now dont have its own constructor property why?since prototype are also the instance of function Object but they have constructor property.

My question is since prototypes are also the instance of the Object function and empty object({}) are also the instance of the Object function ,one lacks the property called constructor and one has.Why is so?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no it dont have its own

Comment: @MaizerePathak: It does for me: http://i.imgur.com/ENMQfJQ.png

Comment: @Blender i said it dont have its own.That construter is inherited from its internal prototype whose value is set to Object.prototype .so from here it is inherited

Comment: @MaizerePathak: Proper spelling, punctuation, capitalization, and spacing help people understand what you're trying to say. We have those things for a *reason*.

Answer (score 2):

**Before your edit**

> x now dont have constructor property

Yes, it does. It inherits it from `Object.prototype`.

This code:

```
var x = new Object();
console.log("typeof x.constructor = " + typeof x.constructor);
```

...outputs `typeof x.constructor = function`. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/udolaf/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/udolaf/1/edit)

**After your edit**

> x now dont have its **own** constructor property

*(My emphasis)*

It doesn't have its *own* property called `constructor` (`x.hasOwnProperty("constructor")` is `false`) because it doesn't have any reason to have it, it's on the prototype.

It's important to realize that the link between an object and its prototype is a *live* link. The object doesn't get a *copy* of the prototype, it gets a reference to it. When we retrieve a property from an object, if the object doesn't have its own property with that name, the reference to the prototype is followed to see if the *prototype* has that property (and so on up the prototype chain all the way to `Object.prototype`). This is the whole point of prototypical inheritance, objects don't have copies of the properties of their prototypes, they inherit from their prototypes.

Here's an example of how it's a *live* link:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.answer = 42;

var f = new Foo();
console.log("[before] f.question = " + f.question);
console.log("[before] f.answer = " + f.answer);

// Note that `f.question` is undefined, of course, as we haven't defined it

Foo.prototype.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";

console.log("[after] f.question = " + f.question);
console.log("[after] f.answer = " + f.answer);

// Note that `f.question` is defined now, even thoguh `f` was created
// BEFORE we added that to the `Foo.prototype`.
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/udolaf/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/udolaf/2/edit)

---

Re your comment:

> My question is since prototypes are also the instance of the Object function and empty object({}) are also the instance of the Object function ,one lacks the property called constructor and one has.Why is so?

Because only the object assigned to `Object.prototype` has actually been **assigned** the `constructor` property. This is part of creating a function (in this case `Object`, but it's true of any function). See Step #17 of [§13.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2) of the specification. All other objects created (literally or otherwise) via `new Object` receive the property via the prototype chain, but the specific object on `Object.prototype` has had that property *directly* assigned to it.

Comment: Crowder u r not focusing on my question.I know those stuff.My question is since prototypes are also the instance of the Object function and empty object({}) are also the instance of the Object function ,one lacks the property called constructor and one has.Why is so?

Comment: @MaizerePathak: Due respect, if you want people to help you, don't keep saying "You're not focussing on my question." (Once was bad enough, twice is fairly rude.) I **am**. You haven't expressed it very clearly, but I think I understand what you're asking now and have updated the answer.